# How to create a sitemap after url rewrite?

Tags: url-rewriting, sitemap, redirect, google-search-console

I have created a URL rewrite and URL redirect from

`www.example.com/?blablabla_ugly_url`  -->  `www.example.com/nice_url`

p.s. It also has some redirection to subfolder.

This is a Wordpress platform.

I can browse and everything is fine.

However, when trying to create a sitemap, I have a **404 response**, saying that the link 'www.example.com/?blablabla_ugly_url' is broken. Shouldn't it be redirected? Why do I get a 404 err?

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your rewrite rules?

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your response. I have debugged and the question turned into a bit different. That's why I decided to post another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865601/can-not-sitemap-after-url-rewrite. I'll appreciate if you could please have a look. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this sitemap generator - http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ - and index the entire site. Their spiders should follow the redirects you've put in-place.