# can not sitemap after url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, sitemap

I have written a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file for my website page:

```
RewriteRule ^nice_url/$  ?p_action=user_profile&post_author=45 [L]
```

The full link is: "http://www.example.co.il/nice_url/" it works perfect.

BUT, when I try to create a sitemap (e.g. with http://www.web-site-map.com/), I have an indication that the link "http://www.example.co.il/nice_url/" is broken.

Why?

The link is working fine. Why is it indicated as broken?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I found the problem:

I have a main .htaccess file that redirects to 3 different folders. Each folder is for a different website (all in the same host).

One of the websites is in WP. The rewrite happens well.

BUT, when I try to generate a sitemap - the wp returns a 404 for the sitemap generator and thats why I get an error.

solution: I'll probably try to rewrite from the php and not from the htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another rule to externally redirect long URL to nice URL like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?p_action=user_profile&post_author=45\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ nice_url? [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE: Alright I checked that sitemap generator is putting `&amp;` instead of `&` in generated URLs.**

You need to add this additional rule to handle this:

```
# convert &amp; to &
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: I never suggested you to replace your rule. This rule was supposed to be added to existing code in order to make it work both ways.

Comment: I added this rule but that did not fix the problem :( my htaccess looks like this now:

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [L,R,NE]

Comment: RewriteRule ^nice_url/$  ?p_action=user_profile&post_author=45 [L]  #rewrite to the correct file

Comment: Both work when I browse to them. But when I try to create a sitemap -->> ERR. p.s. I am not not what is the correct behavour, but I found these: http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/xml-sitemap-file-amp/    http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#escaping (not sure if it helps to solve my issue... but anyway). Thank you verym much for your help!

Comment: Through .htaccess we can only make some nice URLs work or remove some unwanted elements from them. However it cannot make some sitemap generator behave nicely?

Comment: Exactly. The links work fine ( you can try yourself), BUT when generating a sitemap - the generator shows as if there is an err ( you can also try by yourself). Thanks

Comment: As I wrote: `However it cannot make some sitemap generator behave nicely` .htaccess isn't even used by that website for generating sitemap.

Comment: I am a little confused... So what is the problem? I cant generate a sitemap? Why? What to do? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know many sitemap generators but you can try an alternative generator.